# Html5 scrollbar using images

Tags: html, scrollbar

I am going to create a HTML5 JavaScript app and in that I want a floating scroll of images. 
I want to scroll images of a,b,c and I want to do that just by mouse dragging and no scroll bar to be used. Can any one shed light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.horizontal.scroll.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.horizontal.scroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#horiz_container_outer').horizontalScroll();
    });
 </script>

  /* add the necessary HTML*/
 <ul id="horiz_container_outer">
     <li id="horiz_container_inner">
        <ul id="horiz_container">
          <li>Image 1</li>
          <li>Image 2</li>
          <li>Image 3</li>
          <li>Image 4</li>
          <li>Image 5</li>
       </ul>
    </li>    
</ul>        


  <div id="scrollbar">
       <a id="left_scroll" class="mouseover_left" href="#"></a>
       <div id="track">
       <div id="dragBar"></div>
  </div>
           <a id="right_scroll" class="mouseover_right" href="#"></a></div>
   </div>
```

you can use like this..hope it will help for your application

Answer (score 0):

You could use some plugins for achieving this functionality..Many plugin's available for scrolling images.

Try this:

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1118/Awesome-jQuery-scrolling-decks-plugin

Comment: Thanks for the help but I didn't want Jquery piugin I just want to scroll ysing simple HTML5/css thats all. I f you have anything please share it